# How to perform stratified 10 fold cross validation for classification in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation, sampling

My implementation of usual K-fold cross-validation is pretty much like:

```
K = 10;
CrossValIndices = crossvalind('Kfold', size(B,2), K);

for i = 1: K
    display(['Cross validation, folds ' num2str(i)])
    IndicesI = CrossValIndices==i;
    TempInd = CrossValIndices;
    TempInd(IndicesI) = [];
    xTraining = B(:, CrossValIndices~=i);
    tTrain = T_new1(:, CrossValIndices~=i);

    xTest = B(:, CrossValIndices ==i);
    tTest = T_new1(:, CrossValIndices ==i);
end
```

But To ensure that the training, testing, and validating dataset have similar proportions of classes (e.g., 20 classes).I want use stratified sampling
technique.Basic purpose is to avoid class imbalance problem.I know about SMOTE technique but i want to apply this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `crossvalind('Kfold', Group, K)`, where `Group` is the vector containing the class label for each observation. This will lead to sets where each group is proportionally abundant.

Comment: .My class proportion is like this   Value    Count   Percent
     class 1  :   3745     (65.11%)
     class  2 :     728     (14.90%)
     class 3  :   943     (20.00%)